# jQuery mobile slider discretization and decimal digits

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jslider

I am currently using [jslider](http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/) for my application but I am in the need of something more mobile friendly.

I am looking at [the slider in jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/slider/) and it looks cool and all, but I am dealing with scientific data and I need to specify arbitrary discretization (the "step" for the slider).

With jSlider I can do the following:

```
myElem.slider({ from: MIN, to: MAX, step: STEP, round: 2, skin: "plastic", onstatechange: function(value){sliderStateChangeHandler();}});
```

Where:

- **from** / **to** specify my range
- **step** specifies discretization
- **round** is the number of decimal digits

**Q: Can I do all of the above (in particular specify step and decimal digits) with the slider in jQuery mobile and if so can someone please provide an example?**

I could not find anything other than very basic examples [in the documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/slider/).

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the step - [see here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/slider/).

I've not seen anything to round the values to a certain number of decimal places, but you could probably handle that using events.